# Solr Indexing My SQL Timestamp or Date Time field

Tags: mysql, datetime, solr, dataimporthandler

To index Date in Solr, Date should be in ISO format.
Can we index MySQL Timestamp or Date Time feild with out modifying SQL  Select Statement ?

I have used

```
 <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6"     positionIncrementGap="0"/>

 <field name="CreatedDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />

 CreatedDate is of Type Date Time in MySQL
```

I am getting following exception

```
 11:23:39,117 WARN  [org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DateFormatTransformer] (Thread-  72) Could not parse a Date field : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-04-14 11:22:48.0"
```

Any help in fixing this Issue is really appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check Default nature  of datetime field in SOLR

[DatefieldSOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html)

Convert Your datetime value with following mysql function

```
SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as created_at,... from table
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like magic. I spent so much time figuring out parse exception. Even using DateFormatTransformer did not solve my problem. After reading your solution, I was like why I did not think of this.Thanks a lot