# Solr date field doesn't store the time

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, solr

I have a `datetime` field in MySQL that I'm also using in a SOLR index. For some reason, it seems SOLR is loosing the time value and rounds it up to 5AM.

In the database: `2014-09-29 09:01:15`

In SOLR: `2014-09-29T05:00:00Z`

It happens with all `datetime` fields, in 2 separate indexes, regardless of how old the record is. Reindex and cleanup is being done regularly.

From `schema.xml`:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

and later on

```
<field name="gallery_date" type="date" indexed="true"/>
```

I was thinking is a timezone issue, but I'm not doing any timezone transformations or reformatting. The field is added "as is" into SOLR.

My goal is to get correct sorting at the minute/second level, which doesn't work properly right now. Any ideas?

Thank you

SOLR version 3.6.1

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000962/solr-indexing-my-sql-timestamp-or-date-time-field) may help.

Comment: so, you have problem with sorting of with date transforming?

Comment: So, how are you inserting the data in Solr from MySQL? Can I know the approach?

Comment: Mysterion, with date transforming I believe. SSaikia_JtheRocker, I'm using the built in DIH, so just a normal mysql query. Right now I'm testing the solution @mccannf suggested, but my server has problems and I can't reload data-config.xml to see if it worked. I'll update when I get the server working again. Many thanks

Comment: @mccannf While that seems to be the solution, is still not working. I'm formating it as in that question, `DATE_FORMAT(gallery_date,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') as gallery_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4978

I had `convertType="true"` in `data-config.xml` . As a workaround, I've set it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 hrs round up in Solr is probably because of the Type of Solr field selected.

You might have probably used the TrieDateField.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDateField.html